# ValueError: expr must be a string to be evaluated, <class 'bool'> given

Tags: python, pandas, string, input

when I enter France for geo below it gives me the error, could someone please assist?

```
geo = input("Select the country you´d like to analyze (France / Germany / Spain): ")

churn_ds = pd.read_csv('../input/predicting-churn-for-bank-customers/Churn_Modelling.csv', sep=",",).query('Geography' == geo)
```

> `#ValueError: expr must be a string to be evaluated, <class 'bool'> given`

Comment: instead of using `query`, use `churn_ds = pd.read_csv('...')['Geography'==geo]`

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 3):

The method [`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) expects a `string` as argument, if you want to use a boolean statement, the syntax is different

```
churn_ds = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv', sep=",").query(f'Geography == "{geo}"')
churn_ds = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv', sep=",").query(f'Geography == @geo') # takes geo variable

# Or

churn_ds = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv', sep=",")
churn_ds = churn_ds[churn_ds['Geography'] == geo]
```

Comment: Or `df.query('Geography == @geo')`

Comment: @SayandipDutta, could you please provide a reference of the use `@` in this context?

Comment: @navneethc See [`here`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#local-variables)

Comment: Ah, thanks. Good to know, but looks like it's not meant for regular usage.

Answer (score 0):

The query must itself be a string. What you have supplied is a Boolean expression.

Try this instead:

`.query("Geography == {0}".format(geo))` (Python 3)

`.query(f"Geography == {geo}")` (Python >= 3.6)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), the expression has to be a string. So it must go in quotes. Now question is how do you refer to "geo" which is a variable now. See the documentation.

> Parameters
>
> ```
> expr:str
>
>     The query string to evaluate.
>
>     You can refer to variables in the environment by prefixing them with an ‘@’ character like @a + b.
> ```

This clarity has already been pointed out by @sayandip-dutta and @azro, you need to use '@' symbol since "geo" is a variable now.

```py
import pandas as pd
geo = input("Select the country you´d like to analyze (France / Germany / Spain): ")

churn_ds = pd.read_csv('./Churn_Modelling.csv', sep=",").query(expr='Geography == @geo')
print(churn_ds)
```

Gives the following output.

```py
      RowNumber  CustomerId  ... EstimatedSalary  Exited
1             2    15647311  ...       112542.58       0
4             5    15737888  ...        79084.10       0
5             6    15574012  ...       149756.71       1
11           12    15737173  ...        76390.01       0
14           15    15600882  ...        65951.65       0
...         ...         ...  ...             ...     ...
9966       9967    15590213  ...        20393.44       0
9980       9981    15719276  ...        99595.67       0
9987       9988    15588839  ...         1914.41       0
9989       9990    15605622  ...       179436.60       0
9992       9993    15657105  ...       195192.40       0

[2477 rows x 14 columns]
```